# How to perform query on JSON list in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of JSON objects store from `TinyDB` (`python` library). I need to access this with `javascript` and would like to run queries with it.

The data stored in the JSON list is like the return results from a `MongoDB` query. However, I do not want to use `MongoDB` since it requires a server.

Is there a way to run queries on a JSON list in `javascript`?

I've tried to look online, but can only find proper tiny databases with `javascript`. Since I process and extract data with `python` I would like to find a way to share the information seamlessly between them. A JSON list file seems like a good solution but I can't find a way to run queries on it in `javascript`

Comment: you can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to reduce the data to the parts you want, but there isn't a built-in query system in javascript. my own [javascript query language](http://pamblam.github.io/jSQL/) library might be of interest to you though..

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm open to solutions as long as I can *easily* create the data format in python and then shared both ways.

Comment: Are you using node.js?

Comment: @MilesZew Yes. More exactly, writing in `electron`.

Comment: If you have any adodb database you should be able to use the npm package node-adodb to query it. (for example microsoft access databases does not require a server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq.js for filter query..
github.com/neuecc/linq.js